# The difference between 'find' and 'get' in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I created 3 tables : users , roles and role_user.

The user model :

```
 public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }
```

The following is OK, I'm able to get the relation :

$roles = User::find(1)->roles;

But when I do this instead :

```
$roles = User::where('name', 'Test')->get()->roles;
```

I get this error :

`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$roles`

What am I doing wrong?

What is the difference between `find` and `where`?

If I want to use `where` to fetch a relation, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### `get()`

`get()` simply executes whatever (select) query you have built. It will **return a collection** (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`) in any case. That's the reason for your error message. You want the `$roles` of one model but you are trying to get it from a collection, which is obviously not possible.

### `find()`

`find()` is used to fetch *one or many* models by its / their **primary key(s)**. The return value will either be a single model, a collection or `null` if the record is not found.

#### Uses

```
$user = User::find(1); // returns model or null
$users = User::find(array(1, 2, 3)); // returns collection
```

#### Equivalent with `first()`

`first()` returns the first record, so you get a single model even if the result may would contain multiple records

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->first();
```

returns the same as

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

---

Meaning for your case you want to use `first()` instead of `get()`

```
$roles = User::where('name', 'Test')->first()->roles;
```

Answer (score 1):

`get` returns a collection, `find` returns single model. So obviously you can't call `->name` on the collection of users.

```
User::find(1); // single User model
User::find([1,2,3]); // collection of User models
User::get(); // collection of User models
```

There are also other methods returning the query result, eg.:

```
User::first(); // single User model
User::pluck('name'); // single value of name field of the first row
```

and so on.. [read the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)