# Laravel 5 - Undefined property when using relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I started with a basic query which returned project data from a table:

```
$project = Project::find($id);
return view('project.show')->with('project', $project);
```

And then on my page I `dd()`'d the `$project->id` and it worked.

I also now have a table called user.

A project belongs to a user, so I have a relationship set up in my model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And I then do:

```
$project = Project::with('user')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

But I get the error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

If I just `dd()` the `$project`:

```
Collection {#200 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Project {#196 ▼
      #fillable: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:5 [▶]
      #original: array:5 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

To clarify, I want to be able to do:

```
$project->id
$project->user->name
```

Comment: You will find your awnser here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598603/the-difference-of-find-and-get-in-eloquent

Comment: Can you provide your schemas for `projects` and `users` tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get()` method will always return an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object. This means that your `$project` variable is a `Collection`, so when you try `$project->id`, you're trying to access the `id` attribute on the `Collection`, which doesn't exist. This is why you get the error.

There are a couple of different ways to get at what you're trying to do. They are shown in code below. They are all pretty much equivalent.

```
// This is your code, just added the call to first() on the Collection
// to get the first item in the Collection
$project = Project::with('user')->where('id', $id)->get()->first();

// This is a little more efficient. It is calling first() on the QueryBuilder.
// This will directly return the desired object, without having to create
// an intermediate Collection.
$project = Project::with('user')->where('id', $id)->first();

// This is equivalent to the previous statement, just a little cleaner.
// find() is just a shortcut for where('id', $id)->first().
$project = Project::with('user')->find($id);
```

All three of the above statements will get you the `Project` object, which you can then use as you'd like:

```
$project = Project::with('user')->find($id);

// print the id
echo $project->id.PHP_EOL;

// if the user exists, print the name
if ($project->user) {
    echo $project->user->name.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain :) Sorted the issue out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$project = Project::with('user')->find($id);
```

Comment: This statement will return all projects, with all users eager loaded. `find()` will return a model instance, but then calling `with()` on that will return a new query builder, which you then call `get()` on, which will return all the projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

Controller:

```
Project::where('id', $id)->get();
```

Model

```
public function user(){
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

View

```
@foreach($project as $i)
 {{ $i->user->user_id }}
```