# when to use get() in query laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a basic query set up in the show method of a laravel resource

```
public function show($id){
     $results = Student::find($id);

     $drives= Drive:: where('student_id', $id);
}
```

The query for $results works perfectly. The query for $drives does not work unless I do ->get() at the end of it. Why is this? what's the difference between the two queries so that one requires the ->get() and the other does not? Solving this problem took me like 5 hrs and i'm just curious as to the functionality behind it so i can avoid this headache in the future.

Comment: `find()` returns a result for the given primary key (if it exists); `get()` is used to retrieve results from a query builder instance.

Comment: a query buildier is considered "where" or something similar?

Comment: That's just the way Eloquent works
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

Comment: @maximus1127 When you're adding clauses (such as wheres) then that's using the query builder. You then need some way of retrieving the results that match the query you've built up—that's what the `get()` method is for: for _getting_ your results.

Comment: one more question. does "get()" refer to the same "get" as in the $_GET variable? or does it mean more like "get this result" kinda thing? will there ever be a "Model::where('foo', $id)->post()" situation? where it's equivalent to the $_POST variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some `eloquent` expressions have a `get` implicitly. Those ones who are made by a  `Query Builder` will need a `->get()` call, `find(), findOne()...` won't need a `get()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-models

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Answer (score 0):

use get to execute a builder query. unless you run the get() query wont be executed. get will return a collection.

1 - Use query builder to build queries however you want.

```
$drives= Drive:: where('student_id', $id);
dd($drives); // will return a query builder, you can use it to build query by chaining
```

2 - when you are ready to execute the query call get()

```
$drives= Drive:: where('student_id', $id);
$result = $drives->get() 
dd($result); // will return a database query result set as a collection object
```

If you want to get a single object by id use find, to get a single object

```
$results = Student::find($id);
dd($result); will return a single model
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `find()` on a model gets a query result based on the primary key of the model, `id` in this case.

When using `where()`, it gets a collection (an object of all query results), so if you only want the first result you must call `$drives=Drive::where('student_id', $id)->first();`

Here is a more in-depth explanation: [the difference of find and get in Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598603/the-difference-of-find-and-get-in-eloquent#answer-27610932)