# accessing collections within collections laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a table of "rosters" that's pretty much strictly foreign keys. It acceses the "schools" table, "courses" table, and "students" table. So essentially, a 'student' takes a 'course' at a 'school'. My RostersController has this

```
public function show($id)
{
   $roster = Roster::where('course_id', $id);
   return view('roster')->with('roster', $roster);
}
```

My Roster Model is:

```
public function students()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
}
```

My student Model is:

```
public function roster()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Roster');
}
```

my view is this:

```
@foreach ($roster as $child)
  <p>{{$child->id}}</p>
  <p>{{$child->students->first_name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

The rosters table just saves the student_id rather than all of the student's data that is already in the 'students' table. So i'm trying to access the students table from this relation but when i run this, it tells me that anything related to the students table is 'not on this collection'. I know that I could do things this way if i was working with a hasOne relationship, but how can i accomplish this with a hasMany to output the students table value in each row?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
public function show($id)
{
   $roster = Roster::with('students')->where('course_id', $id);
   return view('roster')->with('roster', $roster);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Roster.php

```
public function show($id)
{
   $roster = Roster::with('students')->where('course_id', $id)->get(); // load the students
   return view('roster')->with('roster', $roster);
}
```

On the view

```
@foreach ($roster as $child)
  <p>{{$child->id}}</p>
  <p> 
   <!-- Loop through the stundents since this returns an collection of students and not just one -->
   @foreach($child->students as $student)
    {{$student->first_name}} <br>
   @endforeach
   </p>
@endforeach
```

Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for more information on eager loading

Comment: i apologize,  i put the least amount of code to get the answer that i needed but i need to give more details. I'm actually outputting this to a table row. so the child->id and $student->first_name would need to be on the same row output. if i follow your code exactly, according to the way i originally posted, wouldn't it output one child->id and then every single student? even ones that are not related to that child->id? I ask because i'm going to need to alter it to fit my table needs. How can i get just the student that belongs to that child->id from the student table?

Comment: When you're doing `Roster::with('students')...` you're saying that you want to fetch your `Roster` and it will bring a property named `students`which will be an array of all students that belongTo the `Roster` model. so in each $roster, it has an array of its students

Comment: as I said in the end, check this docs since they explain it better than i can ever do it https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

So, your first issue is, that

```
$roster = Roster::where('course_id', $id);
```

will just return a QueryBuilder instance, you have to use

```
$roster = Roster::where('course_id', $id)->get();
```

then for sure, *students* is a collection, you have to iterate over it like this:

```
@foreach ($child->students as $student)
    {{ $student->yourProperty}} <br>
@endforeach
```

Update:
I saw you know already about that [when to use get() in query laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154377/when-to-use-get-in-query-laravel-5)

Comment: apologies for not being thorough, i actually do have the get() in my code in the controller, i just forgot to type it here in the question. I have not tried to chain 'students' to the entry variable of '$child' like you did right there. i'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The `$child->students` is a collection. So, you need to use another `foreach` loop inside the first one.

Your code should look like this:

```
@foreach ($roster as $child)
    <p>{{$child->id}}</p>
        @foreach($child->students as $student)
            <p>{{$student->first_name}}</p>
            <p>{{$student->age}}</p>
            <p>{{$sutdent->another_column_in_students_table}}</p>
        @endforeach
     <p>{{$child->any_other_column_in_roster_table_if_needed}}</p>
@endforeach
```