# How to display on blade view the contents of a selected id? Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm new to laravel and i'm having a hard time displaying the items of the package that i have selected in my blade view. I can display all packages in one blade view. The goal is to let me view the contents of a package if i click it on the blade view.

PackageItems Table

`id | package_id | item_id | qty`

`package_id` is a foreign key from the `packages` table and `item_id` is from the `items` table

Here's how i fetch the data:

Controller

```
public function showPackageItems($id)
{
    $package = Package::find($id)
    ->with('packageitems')
    ->where('id', '=', $id)
    ->get();
    return view('admin.packages.show')->with('package', $package);
}
```

Package Model

```
public function packageItems()
{   
    return $this->hasMany(PackageItem::class, 'package_id') ; 
}
```

PackageItem Model

```
public function package()
{   
    return $this->belongsTo(Package::class,'package_id') ; 
}
```

showItems Blade view

```
@foreach($package as p)
 <td>{{$p->packageItem->item_id}}</td> //error
 <td>{{$p->qty}}</td> //error as well
@endforeach
```

I already tried to dd($package) and i got the correct results. My problem is how do i display it on my blade view.

Comment: `PackageItems` is a collection so you can't access directly `$p->packageItem` like that. check my post

Comment: @bhavinjr thank you for the explanation. Your code works perfectly, i accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`Controller`

```
public function showPackageItems($id)
{
    $package = Package::find($id)
                     ->with('packageItems')
                     ->where('id', $id)
                     ->first();

    return view('admin.packages.show', compact('package'));
}
```

`Blade file`

```
{{ $package->id }} //you can access package instance like that.

//for packageItems
@foreach($package->packageItems as $p)
 <td>{{ $p->item_id }}</td> 
 <td>{{ $p->qty }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you it's working perfectly. And thank you for the explanation with the collections part i'm still quite new so i need to learn quite a few more things. Accepted as the answer.

Comment: @AnthonyCruz  I glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Controller

```
public function showPackageItems($id)
{
    $package = Package::with('packageItems')
    ->where('id', '=', $id)
    ->get();
    return view('admin.packages.show')->with('package', $package);
}
```

In blade

```
@foreach($package as $p)
 <td>{{$p->packageItem->item_id}}</td> //error
 <td>{{$p->qty}}</td> //error as well
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code on how to retrieve the records

using find and get is different: [the difference of find and get in Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598603/the-difference-of-find-and-get-in-eloquent)

Also you need to get the packageitems first

```
public function showPackageItems($id)
{
    $package = Package::with('packageitems')
    ->where('id', '=', $id)
     ->get();
   return view('admin.packages.show')->with('package', $package);
}
```