# How to show where parent_id = value in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have a categories table and they have following fields.

- id
- name
- parent_id

I want to show category where parent_id = (for example) = 2 but I see this error.

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>
> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\new\shopping\resources\views\Home\networks.blade.php)
>   Previous exceptions
>
> Trying to get property of non-object (0)

NetworkController.php

```
public function networks()
{
    $categories = Category::where('parent_id', 2)->first();
    return view('Home.networks', compact('categories'));
}
```

networks.blade.php

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $categories = Category::where('parent_id', 2)->first();

Just Replace this with

```
$categories = Category::where('parent_id', 2)->get();
```

For Reference, check this link
[the difference of find and get in Eloquent in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598603/the-difference-of-find-and-get-in-eloquent)